# NVIDIA driver not launching X up

Tags: drivers, debian, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I have Debian Wheezy 7.6.0 installed, it's a fresh installation. I was trying to install NVIDIA drivers for my graphics card GeForce GT 540M.

I successfully installed version 304.117, that has my device on supported list. I was following this tutorial ( https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#wheezy ).

The problem is, when I launch nvidia-xconfig, it generates a xorg.conf file for me. When I reboot the system, the X does not launch. There is just a blinking _ cursor, and commands cannot be typed(if that helps, it has proper resolution). When I click the power button in regularly shuts down and I have to rm the xorg.conf in rescue mode to get the X working back.

What causes that freeze on startup and how can I fix it? I will provide any other necessary information about my OS and hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Bumblebee for laptops with multiple graphics cards resolved the problem.